# Key-Value DB (an alternative to Berkeley DB?)

Tags: c++, c, hashmap

I'm looking for a hashmap on disk (Berkeley DB would fit exactly, but for the licensing problem).
The requirements are:

1. FOSS w/a commercial-friendly license (can be used in commercial applications without a fee)
2. a C/C++ interface
3. Embeddable
4. decent speed?  faster than SQLite would be ideal
5. cross-platform would also be nice

Any suggestions welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the *dbm libraries?

dbm ndbm gdbm sdbm tdbm and friends

Plenty to choose from.

Comment: just realized that many of those won't (or at least are not intended to?) compile on windows.  also, many are quite old.
I'm not rejecting them out of hand, I'd just like to hear your thoughts on that

Comment: Hidden requirements (sigh).  sdbm appears to be available for windows.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a couple of recent options, both of which provide a byte[] -> byte[] map, atomic batch updates, and are BSD licensed:

[Leveldb](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) from Google.

[RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org/) from Facebook, which is based on a fork of Leveldb, and claims to provide higher performance on SSD backed storage.

Answer (score 2):

Although your application domain and data specifications are not clear; [RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org), which is a recent solution for embedded persistent key-value storage, seems a fit for you. Benchmarks by Facebook show that it has better performance than LevelDB for server workloads and especially with data larger than RAM capacity. Also it is open-sourced under BSD license. You can find RocksDB C++ examples and [more detail from here](https://medium.com/@aozturk/rocksdb-embeddable-persistent-key-value-store-87f426046687).

Answer (score 0):

If we are strict, none of the suggested mainstream options are hash-maps. Such structures are rarely used for persistent storage because a good hash function would route to different buckets, even for similar keys. Similar keys generally imply related data that is often accessed together, so you want to avoid putting them on remote parts of the disk. Random read latency may be too high.

The most famous matching implementation would be [FASTER from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/FASTER).